# Is there a model of $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb{R})$ which is not a complete ordered field?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, second-order-logic

As far as I understand completeness (every non-empty subset bounded from above has a supremum) is a second order property. Is there a model of $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb{R})$, the **first order** theory of the complete ordered real field, which is not a complete ordered field?

Comment: Yes, I meant the first order theory. I'll add it to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually $\mathbb{R}$ is the only complete ordered field, see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362991/who-first-characterized-the-real-numbers-as-the-unique-complete-ordered-field) MO thread; basically it's because order completeness implies that the order must be archimedean, and any archimedean ordered field is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$. $Th(\mathbb{R})$ is just the theory of [real closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field), so any real closed field other than $\mathbb{R}$ would be an example: real algebraic numbers, real closure of $\mathbb{R}(x)$, etc.

Note that there is another notion of Cauchy completeness of an ordered field. There are plenty of examples of Cauchy complete ordered field.

Answer (score 4):

Of course!

Consider the [hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) ${}^* \mathbb{R}$ for instance. Then the set $\mathbb{R} \subseteq {}^* \mathbb{R}$ is bounded (by any unbounded natural, say) yet it has no least upper bound. Since the hyperreals are constructed to satisfy $\mathsf{Th}(\mathbb{R})$, we get the claim.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Pet peeve: there is no such thing as "the" hyperreals. But any hyperreal field will constitute a counterexample.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, pet peeve validated :P. I know that under CH there's only one ultrapower of $\mathbb{N}$, but $\mathbb{R}$ is too big for the usual saturation argument to go through... Offhand do you know if there's any assumptions (GCH, etc.) that would prove an analogous uniqueness result? I'll probably think about it a bit harder and ask a question if I can't figure it out, that way I can give you some rep for your trouble

Comment: Under $\mathsf{CH}$ there's (up to isomorphism) only one ultrapower of $\mathbb{N}$ *by a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$* - we can still get lots by taking bigger index sets. And a hyperreal field doesn't need to be an ultrapower at all.

Comment: I guess I was thinking of ${}^* \mathbb{R}$ as being a (nonprincipal) ultraproduct of countably many copies of $\mathbb{R}$. This is the definition given in Goldblatt's book, which is my only source for the subject.

Comment: Oh, fair enough. My experience was that a "hyperreal field" is any ordered field satisfying an appropriate transfer property, but I wouldn't be at all surprised to find that there is some terminological inconsistency here (and certainly Goldblatt is a very authoritative text!).

Answer (score 2):

Every ultrapower of $\mathbb{R}$ is elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. it has the same first-order theory) but it need not be complete. In particular, an ultrapower of $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to a non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$ will not be complete.

**Proof.** Let $\mathbb{P}$ be such an ultrapower of $\mathbb{R}$. In other words, elements of $\mathbb{P}$ are functions $f\colon \omega \to \mathbb{R}$ modulo the equivalence relation determined by the ultrafilter. We identify $\mathbb{R}$ with the substructure of $\mathbb{P}$ which consists of constant functions (up to equivalence in the ultrafilter). There is some $f \in \mathbb{P}$ such that $0 < f < r$ in $\mathbb{P}$ for each $r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, e.g. $f(n) := \frac{1}{n}$. If $\mathbb{P}$ were complete, then the set of all such $f \in \mathbb{P}$ would have a supremum, say $s$. But then $s < 2s$, so there is some $r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that $0 < r < 2s$. This implies that $0 < \frac{r}{2} < s$, contradicting the assumption that there is no real strictly between $0$ and $s$.